# Return text length on keyup tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to get current text length, (only text length without html tag) from tinymce editor on keyup. What I do is

1. grab the content using `getContent();`
2. strip the tag using [strip_tags](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/)(not php but custom js)
3. and return the text length.

look:

```
...
setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
        var text = strip_tags(tinyMCE.get('long_text').getContent(),'<img>');
        console.log(text.length);
        });
}
...
```

what I get is the length of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
this is tag-stripped text
```

I need only text length without tags even DOCTYPE, like:

```
this is tag-stripped text
```

but, the problem is it doesnt remove the DOCTYPE, i try to remove it using `regex replace()` but still doesnt work. My English is not good at all, I hope I briefly explain it. The Goal is grab the text from tinymce editor without any tags even DOCTYPE and get the length. How can I do that cerrectly??

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this javascript code using jQuery to get the editors textcontent

```
var plain_text = $(tinyMCE.get('long_text').getBody()).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, evt) {

  console.log($(ed.getBody()).text().length);

}
```

In any case if that's not worked for you try,

```
 ----
 console.log(getStats('long_text').chars);
  -----

// Returns text statistics for the specified editor by id
            function getStats(id) {
                var body = tinymce.get(id).getBody(), text = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);

                return {
                    chars: text.length,
                    words: text.split(/[\w\u2019\'-]+/).length
                };
            }
```